# Initialize integer with value -2**31

Tags: fortran

```
integer, parameter :: m = -2147483648
```

Leads to a compiler error: "Integer too big for its kind", but

```
integer, parameter :: m = -2147483647 - 1
```

seems to work and produce the correct results.  I presume this is because the compiler checks 2147483648 before negating it and overflows the integer type.  While the subtract 1 hack appears to do the desired initialization, is there a "best practice" method to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the Fortran standard defines integers in terms of "model numbers", which have a symmetric interval. GFortran (which you seem to be using based on the error message) does not allow integer literals which are not Fortran model numbers, even though two's complement hardware can represent such numbers. This check is done during the parsing stage, and thus there is no error message when an expression such as "-huge(0) - 1" is constant folded later on during the compilation process.

With GFortran, you can disable this check with -fno-range-check.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, the compiler is interpreting -2147483648 as a unary negation of the value +2147483648, and that intermediate value is too large for a signed 32-bit integer.

As for best practices, every definition of `INT_MIN` I've seen is expressed in terms of `-INT_MAX - 1`:

- [glibc](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.16.0/limits_8h.html#a21658776274b3d146c674318b635a334)
- [dietlibc](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/include/limits.h#L45)
- [linux](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L30)

I conclude that the best practice is to rely on compilers' constant folding to do the right thing, rather than to express this constant directly.

Comment: I'm new to fortran: is best practice then to use `-HUGE( m ) - 1`, or something else?

Comment: Yes, `-huge(m) - 1` seems like your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

2147483648 don't exists, maximum is 2147483647 in 32 bit. You need to use an integer*8 variable, it's a 64 bit integer that lets you use larger numbers.

Comment: Although +2147483648  is not representable in 32-bit twos complement, -2147483648 is.

Comment: Ow, that's true, you're right. Then maybe the problem is what you say, checks before negating.